# Typescript type safe transformation between two types

Tags: typescript

I have a solution that I will post below, but I find it sometime a bit contrived and I'm in the search for a cleaner or different solution, or improvements.

**The problem**

I have an object of type SensitiveData which I want to transform into a SharableData before returning it. For that I need to both add and removed properties on the object. That's the easy part. But I want to do it in a completely type safe way: if someone add a property in SensitiveData without adding it to SharableData, the compiler should warn him about the fact that the transformation is incomplete.

It seems important for security concerns when I transform an object from database into the DTO I want to return.

Exemple:

```
interface SharableData {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    type: DataType;
    priority: number;
    //...
    calculatedValue: number;
}

interface SensitiveData extends Omit<SharableData, 'calculatedValue'> {
    dontShareThis: string
}

const storedSensitive: SensitiveData = getFromStorage<SensitiveData>();
 
// Do something with the data and return a type safe SharableData
```

Obviously, the "simple" way to do it is to create a fresh new object SharableData and assign the properties one by one.

```
const result: SharableData = {
    id: storedSensitive.id;
    name: storedSensitive.name;
    description: storedSensitive.description;
    type: storedSensitive.type;
    priority: storedSensitive.priority;
    //...
    calculatedValue: calculateValue(storedSensitive);
}

return result;
```

It's type safe thanks to TS excess property check, but if the object is big with only 1 or 2 sensible property, the resulting code is verbose. It also require manual update every time something is changed in the model. I have quite large objects, with a single sensitive property, so I want something that work automatically as long as the new property exists in both interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for now

A mapped type Undefined that allow to pass a bunch of properties, matching a Type, but without value:

```
/**
 * Map type to undefined values
 */
type Undefined<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: undefined;
};
```

A removePropToType method, which force me to pass an object with the supernumerary properties of SensitiveData

```
/**
 * Given a types T1 and T2, and an object `base` of type `T1 & T2`,
 * force you to pass a toRemove value that will lead to a pure T2 type object.
 * Warning: Works of first level only.
 * @example
 * removePropToType<PrivateUser, PublicUser>(privateUser, { sensibleProp: undefined, hiddenProp: undefined })
 * @param base The object to cleanup, which should be T1 & T2
 * @param toRemove An object containing undefined value, for each properties of T1 that is not in T2
 * @returns The base object, but with all property from `toRemove` deleted, therefore a T2 object.
 */
export function removePropToType<T1, T2>(base: T1 & T2, toRemove: Undefined<Omit<T1, keyof T2>>): T2 {
    const copy = { ...base };
    Object.keys(toRemove).forEach(key => {
        delete copy[key as keyof T1];
    });
    return copy;
}
```

Then, I can:

```
const result: SharableData & SensitiveData = {
    ... storedSensitive,
    calculatedValue: calculateValue(storedSensitive)
}

return removePropToType<SensitiveData, SharableData>(result, { dontShareThis: undefined });
```

Here, if I add or remove sensitive properties in SensitiveData interface that are not in the SharableData, the compiler will raise an error. It's also a bit safer than the basic solution, as excess property check didn't run in all situations and context.

I'm half happy by the fact that I still need to pass the Undefined object, but it reasonably resolve my issue.